# Switch Case - Break e Return dentro de uma Função - Arduino

Tags: arduino, return, switch, break

Olá, boa tarde! Gostaria de compreender como o switch case funciona na linguagem C++ do Arduino. Tenho a seguinte situação hipotética:

```
estado_principal=0;
estados_Japão=0;

setup () {
}

loop {

switch case (estado_principal) {
    case 0:
    irparaJapão();
    estado_principal=1;
    break;
    
    case 1:
    irparaChina();
    estado_principal=2;
    break;
    
    case 2:
    irparaEUA();
    estado_principal=0;
}
}

void irparaJapão () {


switch case (estados_Japão) {
    
    case 0:
    comprarpassagem();
    estados_Japão = 1;
    break;
    
    case 1:
    checarbagagem();
    estados_Japão = 2;
    break;
    
    case 2:
    pegaroavião();
    return;

}
}
```

1. Nessa situação, para eu sair do switch case dentro da função irparaJapão() e retornar para a próxima linha do código no loop principal (neste caso, estado_principal=1), basta o uso do comando return, como eu coloquei dentro do case 2 do switch case dentro da função irparaJapão()?
2. Caso, por exemplo, eu esteja dentro do case 1 do switch case presente na função irparaJapão(), após executar checarbagagem(), na próxima linha eu declaro estado_Japão=2 (com o objetivo de declarar o valor da variável para a próxima execução do switch case). Após isso eu coloquei o break! O que esse break faz, em meu caso? O meu objetivo é permanecer na função e executar o case 2 do switch case! Como eu faço isso?

Obrigado desde já!